# WFI in a loop prevents debugger to attach

Tags: stm32, sleep-mode

I'm learning STM32F103 MCU and I'm trying to implement "blink led" program with bare metal and systick timer.

Here's what I've came up with:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

static void enable_port_clock(void);
static void configure_pin(void);
static void configure_sys_tick_timer(void);

void start(void)
{
    enable_port_clock();
    configure_pin();
    configure_sys_tick_timer();

    for (;;)
    {
        // asm("WFI");
    }
}

static void toggle_pin(void);

void sys_tick_exception_handler(void)
{
    toggle_pin();
}

static void enable_port_clock(void)
{
    // enable I/O port C clock
    uint32_t rcc_base_address = 0x40021000;
    uint32_t rcc_apb2enr_address = rcc_base_address + 0x18;
    volatile uint32_t *rcc_apb2enr_pointer = (uint32_t *)rcc_apb2enr_address;
    uint32_t rcc_apb2enr_value = *rcc_apb2enr_pointer;
    rcc_apb2enr_value |= 0x00000010;
    *rcc_apb2enr_pointer = rcc_apb2enr_value;
}

static void configure_pin(void)
{
    // configure PC13 as open-drain output with 10 MHz speed
    uint32_t gpioc_base_address = 0x40011000;
    uint32_t gpioc_crh_address = gpioc_base_address + 0x04;
    volatile uint32_t *gpioc_crh_pointer = (uint32_t *)gpioc_crh_address;
    uint32_t gpioc_crh_value = *gpioc_crh_pointer;
    gpioc_crh_value |= 0x00600000;
    gpioc_crh_value &= ~0x00900000;
    *gpioc_crh_pointer = gpioc_crh_value;
}

static void configure_sys_tick_timer(void)
{
    uint32_t stk_base_address = 0xE000E010;
    uint32_t stk_ctrl_address = stk_base_address + 0x00;
    volatile uint32_t *stk_ctrl_pointer = (uint32_t *)stk_ctrl_address;
    uint32_t stk_load_address = stk_base_address + 0x04;
    volatile uint32_t *stk_load_pointer = (uint32_t *)stk_load_address;
    // enable systick exception, enable systick counter
    uint32_t stk_ctrl_value = *stk_ctrl_pointer;
    stk_ctrl_value = stk_ctrl_value | 0x00000003;
    *stk_ctrl_pointer = stk_ctrl_value;
    // set reload value to 500 ms
    *stk_load_pointer = 8000000 / 8 / 2;
}

static void toggle_pin(void)
{
    // toggle PC13
    uint32_t gpioc_base_address = 0x40011000;
    uint32_t gpioc_odr_address = gpioc_base_address + 0x0c;
    volatile uint32_t *gpioc_odr_pointer = (uint32_t *)gpioc_odr_address;
    uint32_t gpioc_odr_value;
    gpioc_odr_value = *gpioc_odr_pointer;
    gpioc_odr_value ^= 0x00002000;
    *gpioc_odr_pointer = gpioc_odr_value;
}
```

Basically I configure peripherals, switch LED in the systick exception handler and just run endless loop in my main code.

This code works just fine, however I don't like that I need to waste cycles in the endless loop, so I tried to insert `WFI` instruction which is supposed to put CPU to the sleep until the next interrupt. Well, program with this WFI instruction uncommented, works fine, at least it blinks the led. However after I flash this program, I can't connect to my MCU with ST-link anymore. I have to switch BOOT0 pin to "1", then I can connect to it again. I tried it with both `WFI` and `WFE` instructions, they act identically.

I guess it breaks some kind of debug functionality, however I don't understand what's the proper way to "sleep forever".

I'm using "blue pill" board with STM32F103 CPU and ST-link debugger ripped from nucleo board. For software I'm using `st-flash` utility from the opensource `stlink` project.

After this "buggy" firmware is written to the MCU, even `st-info --probe` does not show connected MCU anymore.

Actually all this code just doesn't matter. I even tried to comment out everything but the WFI loop and it acts the same.

I also tried to configure System control register (SCB_SCR) and enable SEVEONPEND or SLEEPONEXIT bits, which didn't make a difference.

Comment: I would suggest using CMSIS header files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of WFI is, that it switches off the processor clock (see *Low-power modes* subchapter of PWR chapter in RM0008). The on-chip debugger is part of the processor, so it won't work at that moment, either.

You can set DBGMCU_CR.DBG_SLEEP, which is a bit intended to facilitate debugging with WFI. Some debuggers allow to set this from the debugging interface, IDEs often have some tickbox for this.

Btw. if the blue-pill was cheap, it's [unlikely](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/cheap-bluepill-very-likely-it-has-fake-stm32-right/?all) that you have an STM32F103.

JW

Comment: I tried that as well (all three lower bits). Also tried to enable DMA1 to keep AHB powered (I read about it somewhere in the Internet, RCC_AHBENR, DMA1EN bit). No luck so far. May be it's counterfeit, I'm not sure, it was cheap. So far it worked to the spec.

Comment: I tried simplest program (set bit 0 of address 0xe0042004 and loop wfi) with nucleo f103rb and I was able to attach to it with st-util without any extra "tricks". Without setting this bit, this nucleo board "bricked" too. Blue pill board with the same program "bricked" with all cases. So apparently it seems that MCUs behave differently indeed. Probably not genuine STM.

Answer (score 0):

Reference manual for STM32F103 (RM0008), page 72.
[image]

Just as wek said, WFI disables the processor clock. And your SysTick is clocked from the processor clock. In other words, WFI disables SysTick (if it's configured to use CPU clock as its clock source, which is the most common configuration).

Solution: use another hardware timer. As per this table, no other peripherals will have clocks disabled. Other hardware timers should work just fine.  You don't need to enable any DMA clock or anything, just provide the clock to the timer you will use like you would do for any other peripheral, and it won't need any further intervention from you.

Comment: My issue is debugging. Blink actually works fine, so systick timer is not disabled.

Comment: STM32F103 mentions some debugging stuff too in errata, take a look to rule it out for good

Comment: What if you insert a little delay after the WFI instruction? The errata mentions stuff about quick wakeup, what if that while(1) WFI does something similarly buggy, maybe something with pipeline handling goes wrong. A random guess. At least a dozen extra cycles of non-WFI instructions after WFI would be a thing I would try. Maybe flush the pipeline with ISB here or there?

Comment: I tried four nop's after wfi, no luck. It seems that this MCU is not genuine because I now checked this behaviour with nucleo f103rb which should be genuine and it behaves differently, just setting DBGMCU_CR DBG_SLEEP bit is enough for debugger to work.

Comment: About nop being removed from the pipeline: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/arm-and-thumb-instructions/nop?lang=en be careful with nops, they don't necessarily get executed at all. Maybe just increment a counter there to waste a few cycles. Maybe multiply by 3 every loop for a couple more.